# How linux scheduler decides a process as realtime, interactive, batch

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling, scheduler

When we are writing a program we are not specifying the nature of the process like whether it is realtime, interactive... I read that Linux kernel does scheduling based on the nature of the process. Couldn't find an article explaining how Linux decides on that. Would be nice is someone could give some info that. The question is of academic interest only.

I have read that I can use the system call `sched_setscheduler` to set the scheduler. But what happens when the call is not made?

Also how scheduler decides a process as interactive/batch?

Comment: You don't "write" processes. You write source code, later perhaps compiled to a binary program which gets executed.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Corrected :0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer from [Understanding the Linux 2.6.8.1 CPU Scheduler
By Josh Aas, 2005](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ekubitron/courses/cs194-24-S13/hand-outs/linuxKernelUnderstandingQueudet.pdf#page=14):

> Dynamic priority bonuses and penalties are based on interactivity
> heuristics. This heuristic is implemented by keeping track of how much
> time tasks spend sleeping (presumably blocked on I/O) as opposed to
> running. Tasks that are I/O-bound tend to sleep quite a bit as they
> block on I/O, whereas CPU-bound task rarely sleep as they rarely block
> on I/O. Quite often, tasks are in the middle, and are not entirely
> CPU-bound or I/O-bound so the heuristic produces some sort of scale
> instead of a simple binary label (I/O-bound or CPU-bound).

Answer (score 3):

When sched_setscheduler is not called, then the default scheduling policy is used, which is SCHED_OTHER. That means that the scheduler is round robin/time sharing, in other words: Threads are run in a round robin fashion, and the time sharing part means that sometimes tasks will get swapped out (preempted) if they do not give up the cpu voluntarily in order to allow other threads to have execution time. Additionally there is no notion of process/thread priority with this scheduling policy.

http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setscheduler

Comment: The default scheduling policy isn't strict round-robin.  Linux's standard scheduler uses various heuristics to prioritize I/O bound and interactive processes when they do wake up to do something.    And `nice` levels do bias how much CPU time they get; a nice `-19` task won't starve a niceness `+19` task, but will get many more timeslices.  So there is priority, but it's not strict in the way realtime priority levels work where a higher priority task will always get CPU time.