# Which scheduling algorithm the OS uses in order to distinguish between CPU Bound process and I\O Bound process?

Tags: process, operating-system, cpu

I'm learning about different topics of operating systems, currently about processes.

In order to identify the type of process during its run, which one of the processor scheduling algorithms (short-term scheduling) will fit the most?and why?

1. Multi Level Feedback Queue
2. Round Robin
3. FCFS
4. PRIORITY

My first thought was MLFQ because it dynamically adjusts the scheduling priority of processes based on their recent behavior, allowing the system to adapt to changing workload conditions. But I'm not sure and i am having a bit of trouble finding a clear answer.

Comment: Yes, MLFQ seems the most appropriate answer since it has a concept of waiting processes. In general a process performs IO by asking the OS so the OS always know when a process is waiting for an IO result and it would be trivial for any scheduling algorithm to just not schedule such processes. This is regardless any philosophical classification of the algorithm.

Comment: The actual heuristic Linux uses is to notice when a task blocks on I/O instead of using CPU time up to the end of its timeslice.  See [How linux scheduler decides a process as realtime, interactive, batch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18709848) / https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ekubitron/courses/cs194-24-S13/hand-outs/linuxKernelUnderstandingQueudet.pdf#page=14  - Processes that didn't use up their full timeslice the last few wakeups get a boost in priority when they do unblock, @MargaretBloom, improving interactive latency and I/O throughput (by waking to drain buffers) under high load.